# NPM install doesn't trigger babel build if dependencies not coming from NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, npm-install

For example, if in my package.json, i have this:

```
 "dependencies": {
     "cacheman": "2.1.0"   }
```

it works and it will trigger the building script inside cacheman when I do npm install.

however, if i do this:

```
 "dependencies": {
     "cacheman": "https://github.com/cayasso/cacheman.git"   }
```

it won't work.  npm install will not trigger the build process for cacheman.

why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script you are referring is pre-publish script which runs before publishing the npm module to npm registry. Check here [package.json#L9](https://github.com/cayasso/cacheman/blob/master/package.json#L9)

Extract shown here

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "make test",
    "prepublish": "make"
}
```

When you install it from github there is no publish step so the script is not run.

If you want to install from github only and have the script run, you can add it as postinstall script of cacheman *(you will have to fork the repo to make changes if you are not owner of cacheman)*.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "make test",
    "prepublish": "make",
    "postinstall": "make"//Added postinstall
}
```

Check [examples](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#examples) in npm scripts documentation for more details.